# Adding variable number of days to dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In Excel I want to add 8 days to dates in a column unless the start date is a Saturday, in which case I want to add 9 days.

If A1 has `01-01-2014` then in B1 I want `09-01-2014`.
If A2 has `04-01-2014` (a Saturday) then in B2 I want `13-01-2014`.

Comment: @pnuts If the date is 04-01-2014(which is Saturday) then adding 8 will not solve.(9 is to be added)

Comment: @pnuts =IF(MOD(A1,7)=0,A1+9,A1+8) gives result as 41648 for 01-01-2014. Why it gives that kind of value?

Comment: It works fine. But if i want to add any number of days(say 20.30 etc) then how it can be done? At that time i cant just no.of days+1

Comment: @pnuts Adding just 20 will not work as when u add 20 days it will be having more than one sunday. So it cant be done easily. when adding just 7 days we need to consider a case of saturday only(where 9 to be added and for other days 8 to be added) .so we added 9 in that case

Comment: @pnuts Hey if you delete all your comments(u have deleted some above) then how it can be understood by some new user to this thread as it also contain some points which helps to understand answer. I dont know  whether it is gud practice to delete comments according to stackexchange rules.

Comment: @pnuts ok. So For adding more than 7 days like 20 or 30 etc(any number of days excluding sunday) should i post new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `=IF(MOD(A1,7)=0,A1+9,A1+8)`.

Comment: But if I want to add any number of days(say 20.30 etc) Then how it can be done? At that time I cant just no.of days+1 etc

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A1)=7, A1+9, A1+8)
```

Comment: Does not work. for 01-01-2014 it gives result as 41648

Comment: @ITresearcher Please change the format of the result cell to date format and it wont display 41648.

Comment: ok i got it. also formula should be =IF(WEEKDAY(A1)=7, A1+9, A1+8). But if i want to add any number of days(say 20.30 etc) then how it can be done? At that time i cant just no.of days+1

Comment: @pnuts i have not upvoted this answer. Also in my previous comment i have mentioned the correct answer using WEEKDAY function.

Comment: @ITresearcher Just change the value of 9 to whatever you want(say x), and 8 to (x+1). That should work for you i guess.

Comment: That will not work. Bcoz when u add 20 days it will be having more than one sunday to be considered. So adding 1 will not solve in that case

Comment: @pnuts Yes i understand. The upvote may confuse new readers that this is the correct answer even though it was wrong.